# How can I put quotes around values computed in an f-string?

Tags: python

I'm currently conducting a PR review and came across this:

```py
        value = ""
        for i in uuids:
            value = value + "'" + i + "'" + ","
        where_clause = field + " IN (" + value.rstrip(",") + ")"
```

Nothing particularly wrong with it but I figure it can be improved using f-strings, `join()` and a list comprehension. However it requires me to embed some quotes in my f-string expression and I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's a little explainer. I can run this:

```py
uuids = ["a", "b", "c"]
field = "myfield"
where_clause = f"{field} IN ({', '.join([i for i in uuids])})"
where_clause
```

which returns:

> 'myfield IN (a, b, c)'

but that isn't what's required. What is required is to return this:

> 'myfield IN ("a", "b", "c")'

I've been fiddling around with nested f-strings, `chr()` & escape characters for about 10 minutes but escape characters fell foul of **SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash** and I couldn't figure out the correct incantations to make `chr()` work.

If anyone can figure out how to do this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: if you are trying to execute some SQL, use the inbult methods, for example the cursor object has execute method like `cursor.execute("myfield in (?, ?, ?)", ["a", "b", "c"])`

Comment: I'm not trying to execute some SQL. I'm trying to dynamically build a SQL statement. the returned SQL statement gets executed by something else, which is not the concern of the PR I'm reviewing, nor of this SO post.

Comment: _shrug_. It's not unreasonable for folks to raise a flag (particularly in a comment, keeping answers on-topic) when we see something that looks like a likely security concern, and if you're trusting "UUIDs" from an external source without validating that they _really are_ UUIDs instead of strings like `"); DROP TABLE users; --`, that's a legitimate concern.

Comment: fair point. I've been chastised so many times over the years for supposedly going "off-topic" here on SO that I don't know what is right or wrong anymore. I appreciate the comments, both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this works pretty well, and is "good enough" in this case

```py
uuids = ["a", "b", "c"]
field = "myfield"
where_clause = f"{field} IN (" +  (', '.join([f'"{i}"' for i in uuids])) + ")"
where_clause
```

Comment: Combining `format` and `f-string` is more straightforward: `where_clause="{} IN ({})".format(field, ", ".join([f'"{i}"' for i in uuids]))`

Comment: yes, I agree, that is more elegant. Thank you.

Comment: If you post as an answer I shall mark it as such.